# "Your profile has been saved successfully" but I wasn't editing my profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

For the past couple of days I have been occasionally greeted with the reassuring toast message that my profile has been saved successfully.

The weird thing is that I wasn't editing my profile and haven't done so earlier. I was on the active question tab and all I did was hit the refresh button to make sure I'm not looking at stale data.

I have this issue only intermittently on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/about) and I've verified that the few running scripts on that page are not the root cause of the issue.

[image: All questions page on Stack Apps showing green toast message "Your profile has been saved successfully."]

I'm reporting here to gather more intelligence about occurrences of this spooky message by other users or maybe a satisfying reassurance that this an edge case not to be worried about.

For obvious reasons, I'm concerned when my profile does get changed, one way or the other, specially on a site where I'm a moderator.

Jon Clements cleverly asked: *If you go to the admin page for stackapps and view your own user history does it show a "user edited profile" record?* which I checked and no such record exist on my user history. It is instead littered with me doing moddy things ...

In case it matters: I'm on Chrome latest, Windows 10, [Tampermonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tampermonkey) is the script manager with AutoComments, Lost Soul and Smokey Flag Dialog running. [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin) is also active.

Comment: If you can set Chrome to save a [HAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)), that would make it much easier to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @forestdistrustsStackExchange I've managed to capture an HAR file today when the event  occurred which I will share privately with SE staff on request. Thanks for reminding me to use that feature to obtain technical data, that is helpful.

Comment: Remember to clear your session so the authentication cookies are invalidated before sending the file!

Comment: "*which I checked and no such record exist on my user history.*" based on my testing, clicking "Save changes" without having anything edited will still show the toast message but not store anything on user history though.

Comment: Well, first suspect is one of the userscripts you have installed.